# Dynamically set picture src asp.net

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to set the src of a image with a button click. 
Each of my buttons represents a picture that should be displaying in my "image" area. I need the image Area's SRC property to be affected by the button click.
Im using visual studio 2012 with c#.

-Edit : Using AJAX Update panel in visual studio 2012 with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a postback is acceptable to you for every image change, you may do something like :

In C#:

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            Button btn = (Button) sender;    

            switch (btn.ID) {

                case "btn1": img.ImageUrl = "<Image_Url>"; break;

                case "btn2": img.ImageUrl = "<Image_Url>"; break;            
            }
        }
```

In ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server"  />
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btnClick" />
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="btnClick" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much what i ended up using was :
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {Image1.ImageUrl = ("~/481174_3728211758383_145482873_n.jpg");}

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will be able to accomplish this by using JavaScript and attaching a click handler to the button (onclick="loadImage1()").

loadImage1 function would require you to write the javascript necessary to access the src attribute of the image element and alter it.

You can achieve this with plain javascript (see above concept), or with some javascript library such as jQuery. For cross browser compatibility and to save you from having to write your cross browser safe logic, I would suggest jQuery to handle this.

```
<img id="img1" src="initialimagehere.jpg"/>
```

And then you can change the src attribute like this:

```
$("#img1").attr("src","newimagehere.jpg");
```

jQuery: [this link](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: If I have the buttons assigning values to my session[var] and being used as a trigger for my update pannel; can i still attach javascript functionality to the button as well?

Comment: Yes. The Update Panels just regurgitate the contents that are in the content template so that onclick (for regular html button) or onClientClick (for asp.net button) should be retained. The caveat is that if you change the src value and then the update panel runs, it will re-render and possibly "overwrite" the javascript client side changes. In this case, I would pick one over the other. Having no prior knowledge about update panels in your post, I chose the more direct route.

Comment: You should update your question to include the fact that you are using MS Ajax with update panels. As a side note, you may want to look at jquery's ability to async post to a page to help with setting session info. You could feasibly eliminate the large overhead of the update panel entirely. I would start another question on that if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Inside aspx:

```
<img id="imagenCabecera" runat="server" />
```

And inside aspx.vb:

```
imagenCabecera.Attributes("src") = "url-image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed if I had not first specified a value for ImageUrl in my .aspx code, I could not then set it in the .aspx.cs code.

Ie, if I had my .aspx code as:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="imgPickLg0101" class="ImgSzLarge" />
```

I could not set it in the code behind.

However, if I *first* specified a value for ImageUrl:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="imgPickLg0101" class="ImgSzLarge" ImageUrl="../Images/somepic.jpg" />
```

Then I could set it in the .aspx.cs code:

```
imgPickLg0101.ImageUrl = "../Images/DifferentPicture.jpg";
```